# Is it possible to configure VS2010 to always run as Administrator?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, administration

Does anyone know if you can do this by default rather than having to use context menu?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, right click on your visual studio.exe -> property, go to 'Compatibility' tab, check "Run this program as administrator", click ok to save.

Detailed [step by step guide here](http://www.lancelhoff.com/how-to-run-a-program-in-vista-with-administrator-rights/).

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut, go to its' Properties, click Compatibility tab, under Privilege Level, check 'Run this program as an Administrator'.
Now, everytime you double click the shortuct, it'll run as an Admin.

Answer (score 0):

VS itself does not provide this option, but you can modify the respective shortcut to always run the program as a certain user.

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

No doubt there is. There are also ways you can run all your programs as `root` under Linux. I still wouldn't actually *do* that since it's a bad idea. The first dodgy plug-in you install will zombify your system.